# case in group by in a store procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, group-by, case

is possible do a case in a group by?
 similar to this:

```
select * from table

    GROUP BY 
      CASE WHEN @Attivita=0 THEN (RANK() OVER (GROUP BY Nome,AccountID,Matricola DESC))   

     END
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No: this would make no sense.

You can't

- use GROUP BY and SELECT *
- use RANK in a subclause
- use GROUP BY in the OVER clause
- GROUP BY over a ranking function makes no sense

What are you trying to do, with input/output and schema please.

Edit, based on gaby's answer

```
select
   *
from
    (
    SELECT
        *, RANK() OVER (GROUP BY Nome,AccountID,Matricola DESC) as bar
    from
        table
    ) foo
ORDER BY
   CASE WHEN @Attivita=0 THEN bar END
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to group by all selected (non-aggregated) columns..

so if you `select *` you will need to group by all of them ...

If instead of `group by` you mean `order by` then yes you can..

Comment: You could not use it this way in an ORDER by either, but I've updated my answer based on your "ORDER BY" guess